# jquery videobackground plugin

Tags: jquery, html5-video

i'm using jQuery video background plugin that is working well [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/georgepaterson/jquery-videobackground/tree/1.3)

I Use this code to play the video

```
      $('.video-background').videobackground({
            videoSource: ['../../background_mp4/dock.mp4'], 
            loop:true,
            })
```

and this to stop it

```
     $('.video-background').videobackground('destroy')
```

What I need to do is find its current status IE is it playing and what is it playing ?, I have been through the plugin but can get this information

Can anyone offer some advice please ?

Thanks Mick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the plugin provides for listening to just two events - preloaded and loaded - via the `preloadCallback` and `loadedCallback` options respectively.

Unfortunately, these callbacks appear to have a context, `this`, referring to the container element on which `.videobackground()` was invoked. For your purposes, it would be nice if the context was the video element (or for the video element to be passed as a parameter).

You will have to go digging in the DOM (using Firebug or similar) to discover how to address the video element then, in the preloadCallback or loadedCallback, put listeners (event handlers) in place, which obtain and display the data you require.

Assuming the video to be an HTML5 `<video>` element, then an abundance of documentation/tutorials exists. If not, then all is not lost - you will just have to research/research/research.